# Контроль ввода данных пользователем

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Доброй ночи. Работаю с PascalABC.Net. Интересует контроль ввода данных пользователем (так, чтоб можно было вводить лишь число, а при вводе не числа, а любого символа выдавало сообщение "Введено не число" и возвращало для исправления на ту строку где была сделана ошибка), как это реализовать в моей программе и куда вставлять так скажем? 
На данный момент выводит такую ошибку при вводе например буквы "а"[image: Ошибка при вводе буквы "а"]
А вот собственно и сам код:

```
program Gauss1;
{Решение СЛАУ по методу Гаусса}

uses crt;
const num=5;
      c=0.00000001; {Константа для обхода деления на 0}
var a: array [1..num,1..num] of real;
    b, x: array [1..num] of real;
    n, i, j, k: integer;
           delenie: real;
var
  s:string;
  err:integer;
  v:integer;
begin
 val(s,v,err);
  if err<>0 then
  writeln('Введено не число');
  writeln;
 clrscr;

 writeln('Решение СЛАУ по методу Гаусса.');
 writeln;
 writeln('Введите колич-во неизвестных величин и нажмите ENTER:');
 readln(n);
 writeln;

 writeln('Вводите коэфф-ты матpицы A по стpокам нажимая ENTER:');
   for k:=1 to n do
    for j:=1 to n do
     begin
      write ('a[',k,',',j,']=');
      read(a[k,j]);
     end;
  writeln;
   writeln('Введите вектоp В свободных членов нажимая ENTER:');
    for k:=1 to n do
     begin
      write ('b[',k,']=');
      read (b[k]);
     end;

  writeln;
  writeln('Расширеная матрица:');
  for i:=1 to n do
   begin
    for j:=1 to n do
        write (a[i, j]:5:3,' ':2); {Вывод матрицы с отступами}
        write (b[i]:5:3,' ':2); {Вывод вектора с отступами}
        writeln;
   end;
  writeln;

    writeln('         Прямой ход         ');
    for i:=1 to n-1 do {Строки}
   begin
     for k:=i+1 to n do {Стобцы}
       begin
         if a[i,i]=0 then a[i,i]:=c; {Обход деления на 0}
         delenie:= -1*(a[k,i] / a[i,i]); {Элемент след. урав-я делим на 
элемент ведущего урав-я и умнож. на -1}
         for j:=1 to n do {Еще счетчик}
           a[k,j]:= a[k,j] + a[i,j] * delenie; {К след. уравнению 
прибавляем ведущее...}
         b[k]:= b[k] + b[i] * delenie; {и умножаем на рез-тат деления}
       end;
   end;
    writeln('           Результат прямого хода:        ');
    for i:=1 to n do
      begin
       for j:=1 to n do
        write (a[i, j]:5:3,' ':2); {Выводим на экран...}
        write (b[i]:5:3,' ':2); {результат прямого хода}
        writeln;
      end;
    writeln;

    writeln('обратный ход');
    for i:=n downto 1 do
    begin
      for j:= i+1 to n do
          b[i]:= b[i] - a[i,j] * x[j]; {Раскурчиваем уравнение...}
          x[i]:= b[i] / a[i,i]; {в обратном порядке}
     end;

    writeln('ОТВЕТ:');
    for i:=1 to n do
     writeln('X[',i:1,']=', x[i]:1:2, '.');

   readkey;
end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
S:STRING;
C:INTEGER;
```

begin
REPEAT
  writeln (' Введите значение x=') ;
  readLN(S) ;{читаем строку}
  VAL(S,X,C);{пытаемся преобразовать ее в число, в переменную C - упадет позиция, с недопустимым символом}
  IF C<>0 THEN WRITELN('Должно быть число');
UNTIL C=0;

Comment: Это пробовал, работает, но не так как нужно, не доработанный код вроде

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример обработки ввода значений именно для **PascalABC.NET**:

```
function ReadRealValue(msg : String := '') : Real;
begin
  var error := True;
  repeat
    try
      Result := ReadLnReal(msg);
      error := False;
    except
      WriteLn('Ошибка ввода действительного значения!' + NewLine + 'Повторите воод.');
    end;
  until Not error;
end;

function ReadIntValue(msg : String := '') : Integer;
begin
  var error := True;
  repeat
    try
      Result := ReadLnReal(msg);
      error := False;
    except
      WriteLn('Ошибка ввода целого значения!' + NewLine + 'Повторите воод.');
    end;
  until Not error;
end;

begin
  var x := ReadRealValue('Введите значение x =');
  var n := ReadIntValue('Введите значение n =');
end.
```

Comment: компилятор мне выдает ошибку "Нельзя преобразовать тип real к integer" в строке Result (когда она второй раз вводится)

Comment: Сорри… Просто скопипастил функцию, забыв заменить ReadLnReal на ReadLnInteger.